# Why does small html elements with 1-2px height vary it's height depending on the device resolution?

Tags: html, css

I have this menu icon which is created from a `span` tag and `::before ::after` elements which looks somenthing like this:

```
     <div>
        ::before
        <span />
        ::after
     </div>
```

[image: Hamburguer menu]
The above image the browser is at 100% zoom

When I zoom in and out inside the browser the elements vary their height, so from `2px` of height they seem to have `1px` or something in between

[image: Menu at 150% zoom]
The above image the browser is at 150% zoom

At 150% zoom it's the closest to the correct display, but the middle but seems a little of.

I already tried a to change the parent height, spacing, everything I could think, but I'm not sure where the issue is coming from.

Comment: Browsers struggles with sub-pixel displaying

Comment: The problem here is not the "black bars" height, but the *empty space* between them. The browser is rounding the numbers because they are not integers. Then you get that inaccurate rasterization. This could be solved by specifying a fixed size for the white space (e.g.: 3 or 4px in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Some tiny HTML elements, like your menu icon, may seem to wobble because gadgets we have these days usually have a pixel ratio that's more than 1. That happens when logical pixels don't match well with the physical pixels on the screen. Also, when you zoom in, the number of logical pixels on the screen changes, which can cause small elements like your menu icon to seem like they're changing size as the browser adjusts to match the physical pixels on the device. <s>You can try using SVG's for small icons instead of HTML.</s>

Comment: Remember SVGs are also HTML nodes. They will also have moving parts as groups (`g`) of `path`(s) and multiple geometric shapes. Whether or not each part fits perfect pixels depends on its measures and styling. As *common* HTML elements do.

Comment: @Leo However SVGs are vector-based which means they are scalable without losing quality. I assume that should eliminate the problem of the wobbling and shifting of small elements. Also SVGs are becoming HTML nodes if you are using them in inline way, isn't it?

Comment: they are vectors, they can scale, you are right. What I'm talking about is the *rasterized result* after that scaling. Shapes may not match pixels leading to results like the one in this case, that happens often. That's why, in some cases, people avoid SVGs because of the *poor geometry*, even when using `geometricPrecision`. SVGs are XML files, they can be rasterized on client or server-side, thus, the result is always a rasterized XML.